# plsql escape non url safe characters

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g

I am using plsql to send some http requests to a REST service. Part of the request is some plain text user data which can contain any character. I need to escape characters such as #, &, ? etc. How can I escape non safe url characters such as these? I do not own the code so I can't use third party libraries.

Comment: Escape them, replace them or not sending the request upon detection of invalid characters?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [UTL_URL.ESCAPE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/u_url.htm#ARPLS71589) function?

Basically, the package UTL_URL has two functions that provide escape and unescape mechanisms for URL characters. Use the escape function to escape a URL before the URL is used fetch a Web page by way of the UTL_HTTP package. Use the unescape function to unescape an escaped URL before information is extracted from the URL.

For example:

```
SELECT UTL_URL.ESCAPE('http://www.acme.com/a url with space.html') FROM DUAL;
```

returns:

> http://www.acme.com/a%20url%20with%20space.html

More examples [here](http://psoug.org/definition/utl_url.htm)

You can also use it partially:

```
SELECT 'http://www.acme.com/search?check=' || UTL_URL.ESCAPE('some data'); FROM DUAL;
```